# Build app for Universal but keep iPhone mode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, iad

I want to make an app universal but I want to keep the app from blowing up my app into ipad mode which messes with everything.

I built my app for iPhone only. I need to make it universal so I can run iAds on ipads, but I don't want to rebuild the interface to fit the iPad resolution. Is there a way I can just keep the app running on iPhone compatibility mode on iPads with universal mode on?

Comment: I'm not sure it's possible, but even if it were it would be rather unfair to charge iPad users for an app which isn't technically optimised for it, but have been tricked into thinking it is because of its 'Universal' badge. Unless of course it's free, but then that's just bad UX. I'd be surprised if Apple didn't reject it too.

Comment: @sooper of course it's free. I tried changing the values on Targeted Device Family which kept the Universal badge, and Debug to iPhone/iPad and I changed Release to iPhone, but no go.

Comment: You are asking for a contradiction. By definition, a universal iOS app does not run in iPhone compatibility mode on the iPad.

Answer (score 0):

No.  Either you switch your app to universal in the project settings and provide an interface for each form factor, or you keep it set to iPhone in which case the user can "blow up your app" when they run it on the iPad.